# Python can't access the screenshot it just took on Windows startup

Tags: python, windows, screenshot, pyinstaller, startup

I made a python script that runs at startup, takes a screenshot and sends it to a website. I made an .exe from this script using pyinstaller.

The program works just fine when executed manually, but when it runs from startup, i get the following error:

"Permission denied: imagename.png"

The exe is located in the windows startup folder.

Here is my code

```py
try:

    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()

    file_name = 'ss-' + nume + "-" + str(random.randint(0, 1000)) + '.png'

    pic.save(file_name)

    f = open(file_name, 'rb')

    form_data = {
        'image': (file_name, f),
        'nume': ('', str(nume)),
    }
    response = requests.post('http://website.com', files=form_data)
    print(response)

    k = 1
    f.close()
    os.remove(file_name)
except Exception as e2:
    print('sserror ', e2)
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is trying to put the screenshot file into the startup folder too. Not a good idea even if it did work! Have you tried putting the exe in another folder, and just putting a shortcut to it into the startup folder?